# I have an abstract class and 2 subclasses. How do you work with them if you cannot instantiate the abstract class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, abstract

I have an abstract class and 2 subclasses. How do you work with them if you cannot instantiate the abstract class. I had written code that initially used a class and subclass and later realised I would be best to have 2 subclasses from the parent class. I understand this is a way of doing multiple inheritance in Java. My existing code was instantiating the parent class and I was
working with that. Now, I cannot instantiate the parent class as the class is now abstract.
Is it only the subclasses I can now instantiate? These are normal classes.

One subclass is employee and has date of birth, salary and the other subclass is customer and has  favouritefood, paymentdetails

The parent class is person

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate parent class. You have to use it for example for next reason:

You can keep there some general usefull method which you can use (and link to it by the variable of parent class) in you subclasses (also you can override it if you need), for example:

```
    abstract class Person{
       protected String name;
       protected String surname;
       public String getFullName(){return name+" "+surname;}
    }
    public class Employee extends Person{ 
       public Employee(String name, String surname){
          this.name=name; this.surname=surname;
       }
    }
    public class Mister extends Person{
       public Employee(String name, String surname){
          this.name=name; this.surname=surname;
       }
       public String getFullName(){return "Mr. "+name+" "+surname;}
    }
```

and then you can do so:

```
    Person p1=new Employee("Jonh","Doe");
    Person p2=new Mister("Jonh","Doe");
    p1.getFullName(); //John Doe
    p2.getFullName(); //Mr. John Doe
```

PS: abstract class is not for multiple inheritance, multiple inheritance means another thing (class can be inherited from multiple parents)

Comment: Thanks Puhan, what is this relationship if it is not multiple inheritance? Is it showing polymorphism

Comment: Yes this example shows polymorphism too. I don't know how can we call multiple inheritance from one parent. But expression multiple inheritance usually means different thing :) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

Comment: Thanks Puhan, I am learning as I am going along. I am doing an introduction course to Java.

Comment: If you have any questions about Java - I can give you my email or skype and we can talk about it (It will be pratice for free for my poor English and practice in Java for you for free :), I think I can help you (some time ago, I've passed Java exams and get 2 Oracle certificates).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. Abstract classes can't be instantiated, only classes that fully implement them can.

And if your logic it sound, you shouldn't even need to. I mean, do you ever want to create just a `Person`, or is it always either `Employee` or `Customer`?

Also, if a class is extended by multiple others, it's not called multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is when a single class extends multiple others.

In Java, you can only extend one class, but you can implement multiple interfaces. (but that's outside the scope of the question I guess)

Comment: Hi Luchian, I was hoping to continue using Person in my code. My existing code was instantiating a Person using the constructor and I was instantiating with parameters and then using the class methods to get and set attributes and using with attribute validation code.  I am not sure if I can continue to use Person in the same as with my existing code. I do know my validation code would have to change  to handle the 2-3 new attributes in each subclass that are in addition to the 9 I have in the Person superclass? If customer and employee extends Person is that multiple inheritance?

Comment: @daveb you can still use Person, just not instantiate it. `Person p = new Employee()`. Or you could use an abstract factory if it makes things easier.

Comment: No, it is not multiple inheritance. Example of multiple inheritance (not supperted in Java): Ferrari extends Car, CoolThing;

Comment: Thanks Luchian and Puhan, I am going to change the code to point my person to either an employee or a customer. The only downside isto get by scanner input into attributes variables which I will need to pass into new customer(s) and new employee(s). I was using an attribute called role for the Person s all my code including validation is geared around this. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
public abstract class Person {
    // details left out
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    // details left out
}

public class Customer extends Person {
    // details left out
}
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
Person e = new Employee();
Person c = new Customer();
List<Person> = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

You just have to point each `Person` reference to a valid concrete subclass.

Now that you know something about inheritance, you'll want to know about the Factory class and virtual constructors.  That allows you to create new instances of different kinds of Person in such a way that you keep "if" checks out of client code.

Comment: Thanks duffymo. This makes sense. I have an arraylist for person and it looks like I will need to check that every employee and customer I create is a person before adding to the person arraylist.

Comment: No, you don't have to check.  An Employee IS-A Person; a Customer IS-A Person.  No need to check.  That's what inheritance and the Liskov substitution principle are all about.  If you're smart, you'll make sure that you can iterate through collections of Person and call methods without having to ask what kind of Person you're dealing with.  That's the beauty and elegance of polymorphism.  If you can't do that, you've designed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for next answer, but I want tio answer to your comment about validation:
You can do it so:

```
    class Person{
         .....
       boolean validate(){return !name.isEmpty() && !surname.isEmpty();}
    }

    class Employee{
       ....
       boolean validate(){return super.validate() && salary>0;}
    }
```

Comment: Luchian, thats quite interesting how you use the validation. I was using string length > 0 instead of isEmpty(). I was not aware of this method. Does this cater for null and ""?